# is there any advantage in using Raspbian Buster instead of Stretch on a Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero, raspbian-buster

I was wondering if are there some real advantages in using Buster on a Raspberry Pi Zero, or I should continue using Stretch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you doing with this Pi Zero ?

If you're doing some project **without connection to internet** or **just locally** (*home automation*, etc) I would say no. If no **big bug endangering** your project has been corrected it may no be worth the time and effort required to put again in place your project.

Now, if your Zero is **hosting some web server**, everything **opened to the world** it could benefit from **kernel updates** and other **software updates**. (Some of them could be **patching vulnerability**, etc).

In short it's down to safety en reliability against the time you will have to invest to update your project to this new OS.

Comment: I'm using it in a project without connection to internet, just a camera and a USB stick, since I have to set up a new SD card if I there are no advantages I'll install Stretch again

Comment: Are you exporting the images to your USB stick ?
I believe it falls in the first category, you may benefit by keeping the **Stretch** version which may be lighter

Comment: exactly, I need it to be as light, low energy consumption, and fast as possible

Comment: Keep Stretch lite